# Why does a Mattcher throw an exception after a successful find

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a loop that will find all the instances of "${arbitraryTextHere}" in an input string. E.g:

> someText${findMe}moreText${findMeToo}EvenMoreText${DontForgetMe}

Here is my code:

```
    Pattern placeholderPattern = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{[\\w|\\d]+\\}");
    Matcher placeholderMatcher = placeholderPattern.matcher(templateString);

    int workingIndex = 0;
    while(placeholderMatcher.find()){
        workingIndex = placeholderMatcher.start();
    }
```

Note: The templateString I'm testing this out with is `S"omeString ${someProp}"`

The strange thing is that `.find()` has to return true in order to get inside the loop, but then `.start()` throws an IllegalStateException. The reason why this is so strange is that `.start()` only throws an IllegalStateException if the matcher's internal `first` variable is less than 0, but `.find()`, via the Matcher's `boolean search(int from)` method, will make sure that `first` is zero or greater unless no match is found, but if no match is found then `.find()` will return false, and we won't wind up in the loop body.

So what exactly is going on here?

Update: So I'f I encapsulate the above code so that it all runs in one unit test then it works. So I think the problem is related to having it in a class who's method is called from the unit test. But that's kind of weird. I'm going to dig into this aspect of the problem a bit more and then post an update.

Update: Ok, well I tried turning it off again and on again (I restarted my IntelliJ and recompiled my code) and now it's not broken anymore, so I think i must have screwed something up in that department.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Are you sure you aren't calling `find()` and `start()` anywhere else?

Comment: I'm sure I'm not. One thing I noticed is while trying to debug through the above is that there was some weird reflection stuff going on. I wonder if this is because I was running the above code via a unit test. I'll break it out into it's own test method so that I can post a legit SSCCE.

Comment: Not that it is related to your problem but your `[\\w|\\d]` seems to be not correct since (1) `\\d` is already part of `\\w`, (2) placing `|` inside `[...]` will not mean OR, but change it to literal so your class will also accept `|` character.

Comment: Are you using the matcher in a non-thread safe manner? For example if you have many unit tests sharing the (maybe static) instance executing in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the last update on my question, restarting IntelliJ and recompiling my code fixed things.